# Releasing an R package with several large text fles

Tags: r, r-package

I'm currently creating an R package, and my scripts require before any analysis is done that 3-4 text files be loaded. Normally, I would run the scripts with the following:

```
library(data.table)
session_data = read.table("/path/name/to/filename.txt")
```

and then refer to `session_data` throughout the analysis.

However, in order to release this as an R package, I believe that these files must be downloaded at the time on the package installation.

(1) Normally, how are text files distributed in R packages? Are these gzipped? Where are they placed?

According to http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html, all .text files should be `inst/extdata` I guess. However, it's not clear to me how to "link" to this data within the R package. Also, users would be able to easily access these text files, which I'm not sure is really necessary or desired.

How have other packages dealt with this? (Is there a size limit?)

(2) In this case, should the function loading the text file be executed about loading the R library, `library(package_name)`? Is there more appropriate option?

Comment: save your data as `.RData` and place it inside the `data` subfolder in your package. This way, whenever you call your package, you can access the data with `data(xxx)`

Comment: try not to load a new data-set in your function. it's harder to troubleshoot with a non-generic function.

Comment: @AdamQuek Wouldn't I have to combine all text files together? That may get confusing...

Comment: `inst/extdata` should be a directory, not a file. (If you're using devtools, you can stick stuff there with `use_data`.) You can access its contents independent of OS with `system.file`. [There is a not-too-negotiable size limit of 5Mb for CRAN](http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/size-and-limitations-of-packages-on-cran/), if that's the eventual destination. If not, you could ostensibly make the data as large as you like, though at some point there are better ways to store data.

Comment: @alistaire When is the appropriate time to load the data? If this is in a particular function, I may be re-loading this data each time, which is inefficient.

Comment: Is it internal or external (user-available) data? If the former, store it as .RData, which is a binary format that will load much more quickly than a CSV or whatnot, and make it easily available to your functions. Careful loading really big things, though; you don't want to suck up so much memory you crash somebody's session.

Comment: If you store it as internal data, R will handle when it's loaded for you (via a promise, I believe, though I doubt the data persists between calls). While you could load a user-visible dataset on package load, that seems dicey. I'd instead make the data a user-available default parameter to your function, so they can save it or remove it from their global environment at will.

Comment: This may also be a question well suited to https://community.rstudio.com/ where there are a bunch of people with package-development experience.

Comment: @alistaire But when do I load it and assign it to a variable, e.g. `session_data`? In a function?

Comment: Functions have their own environment, so if you assign it normally in a function, it will disappear with the environment. Usually that’s good. You can deliberately break that behavior if you like, and assign it to the global environment from within the function (and go search for it when run again), but make sure that behavior is really well justified and explained in the documentation if you choose that route.

Comment: @alistaire "Functions have their own environment, so if you assign it normally in a function, it will disappear with the environment" That would significantly slow down functions if used multiple times, correct?

Comment: Only if loading data into memory is a significant bottleneck, which for the data which tends to be put in packages it's not. Most larger data that does get put in packages is exported as a dataset, not as a function, which allows users to load the data into their global environment once and interact with it directly from there. What size of data are you talking about, though, and is there a reason you don't want it user-facing?

Comment: @alistaire It's still several MB of a tarbell...I'll try it. Isn't there a "define global variables upon loading the library" function?

Comment: You can by supplying [an `.onLoad` function](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Load-hooks), with another hook to clean up afterwards so as not to hog memory. You may want to give it a name that starts with `.` so it will be invisible and unlikely to cause a name clash. That said, as a user, that behavior would make me uncomfortable; it's better for a package to be upfront about what resources it uses. You're likely optimizing something that's not the bottleneck: `nycflights13::flights` is 40Mb and still loads in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @allistaire "You're likely optimizing something that's not the bottleneck" Hmmm, good point. I've always been suspicious of `.onLoad` for global variables. Inside a function should work then